# Implementing bitwise operations using pari c library

Tags: c, pari

I am new to using the PARI C library.

How can I perform bitwise ('and' or 'or') operations on the GEN type variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `gbitand` and `gbitor` ?

Declared in `arith2.c` see [this link](http://modular.math.washington.edu/sagesrc/sage/libs/pari/decl.pxi.txt) (sorry for the not so direct link):

```
GEN     gbitand(GEN x, GEN y)
GEN     gbitor(GEN x, GEN y)
```